# How can I convince hyperref and xindy to play together nicely?

Tags: hyperref, indexing, xindy

I'm using `xindy` to generate indexes for a manual that gets translated into multiple languages.  Unfortunately, `hyperref` and `xindy` don't like to play nicely together. I found some older mailing list threads that suggest that fixing this in `xindy` would require too much effort.

My question is: how can I get `xindy` and `hyperref` to play nicely together. What is the best workaround for this incompatibility?

An example document will demonstrate the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\index{single}
\index{range|(}
\lipsum
\index{range|)}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I compile this document (named `x.tex`) using `xelatex` and `xindy`:

```
xelatex x
xindy -C utf8 -M texindy -L english x.idx
xelatex x
xelatex x
```

Page numbers that are part of a range are missing from the index:

[image: Missing page range numbers]

The `xindy` output makes a few complaints:

```
WARNING: Found no :close-range matching an already opened one!
         Location-reference is 1 in keyword (range).
         Maybe I lost some of the regular location-references.

WARNING: Found a :close-range in the index that wasn't opened before!
         Location-reference is 2 in keyword (range)
         I'll continue and ignore this.
```

These errors make sense when we look at the `x.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{single|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{range|(hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{range|)}{2}
```

The `hyperpage` command isn't used in the close-range entry.

In order of preference, here are my desired outcomes:

1. `xindy` and `hyperref` work perfectly together and generate indexes with hyperlinked page numbers without any external processing.
2. `xindy` and `hyperref` can generate indexes with hyperlinked page numbers with the aid of an external script to pre- or post-process the index files before/after passing them through xindy.  (I'm not currently using any special formatting for page numbers if that simplifies things.)
3. `xindy` can be pacified by removing hyperlinks from the page numbers (with or without the use of an external script).

Alternatively, is there a different indexing program that can work with UTF-8-encoded files, `hyperref`, and knows to collate various languages?

Comment: @Stephen: That perl script failed to run for me. It initially complained about an unmatched `(` in the regex. I escaped the `(` with backslashes, but then it just made a message of the `.idx` file.

Comment: @Stephen: That only adjusts the second line of the `.idx` file shown above. `xindy` reports the following: `WARNING: unknown cross-reference-class `hyperindexformat'! (ignored)' and the pagae range still doesn't appear in the index.

Comment: OK, another experiment (Lacking the knowledge I'm doing trial and error here, sorry): What happens when you _remove_ the `hyperpage` from `\indexentry{range|(hyperpage}{1}`?

Comment: Then I get “range, 1, 2” in the index (as opposed to the expected “range, 1–2”. But at least xindy doesn't balk.

Comment: No hyperlinks, just the page numbers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Simple ranges

In `hyperref` 2012/11/06 v6.83m the encapsulating command will be repeated, if it is not explicitly given for the closing range entry. Then both `Makeindex` and `xindy` should be happy in case of simple ranges:

```
\index{...|(}
\index{...|)}
```

The `.idx` file will contain `hyperpage` in both cases.

### Formatting commands

From the manual page of `xindy`:

> For raw index entries in LaTeX syntax,    `\index{aaa|bbb}` is
>   interpreted differently. For    MakeIndex `bbb` is markup that is
>   output as a LaTeX    tag for this page number. For xindy, this is a
>   location attribute, an abstract identifier that will    be later
>   associated with markup that should be output    for that attribute.
>
> For straight-forward usage, when `bbb` is `textbf` or    similar,
>   we supply location attribute definitions that    mimic `MakeIndex`'s
>   behaviour.
>
> For more complex usage, when `bbb` is not an    identifier, no such
>   compatibility definitions exist    and may also not been created with
>   current `xindy`. In    particular, this means that by default the
>   LaTeX    package `hyperref` will create raw index files that    cannot
>   be processed with `xindy`. This is not a bug,    this is the
>   unfortunate result of an intented    incompatibility. It is currently
>   not possible to get    both `hyperref`'s index links and use `xindy`.
>
> A similar situation is reported to exist for the    `memoir` LaTeX
>   class.
>
> Programmers who know Common Lisp and Lex and want to    work on a
>   remedy should please contact the author.

### Ad 3.

Easy, `hyperref` index redefinitions are suppressed by

```
\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}
```

Maybe there is a way to insert `\hyperpage` for linked page numbers in `xindy`.

### Minimal page range

`Xindy` make page ranges starting with *three* consecutive page numbers. This can changed by setting `:min-page-range` to `1` (default is `2`). The following file `mypagerange.xdy` also includes `page-ranges.xdy` that contains the definition of the range separator:

```lisp
; File mypagerange.xdy
(require "page-ranges.xdy")
(define-location-class "arabic-page-numbers"
                       ("arabic-numbers") :min-range-length 1)
```

Then `xindy` is called with option `-M mypagerange.xdy`.

Comment: thanks for the `hyperref` update! It looks like it pacifies `xindy` for the most part. The only remaining problem is that `xindy` shows the “range” entry as “range, 1, 2” instead of “range, 1–2” (despite my specifying `-M page-ranges.xdy` to `xindy`). `xindy` lodges no complains against the new index file. Any ideas there?

Comment: The `mypagerange.xdy` script worked perfectly. Thanks, Heiko!

Comment: `\hyperpage` for linked page numbers can be inserted with `(markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "})`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the solution that worked for me (based on Heiko's and michal's replies).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}
\def\xindyopt{-M indexstyle}
\makeindex[options=\xindyopt]

\begin{filecontents*}{indexstyle.xdy}
(require "page-ranges.xdy")
(define-location-class "arabic-page-numbers"
                       ("arabic-numbers") :min-range-length 1)
(markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\index{single}
\index{range|(}
\lipsum
\index{range|)}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this solution reveal anything new?

Comment: It corrects a syntax error in michal's answer and simply puts everything together for struggling texnicians like me that are trying to compile their first index.

Answer (score 1):

Ad 2)

```
perl -pi -e 's/\|\)/\|hyperpage\)/g' myfile.idx
```

after the first `latex` call, before the `xindy` call.

Comment: Sorry to necro this question, but six years later, this bug still hasn't been fixed. Your perl script works correctly in isolation, but I can't manage to add it to my build chain in TexStudio. I've tried putting it at every point in the compilation process, and I added it to the texindy command, all to no avail. Any ideas?