# How do I use xindy with XeTeX and hyperref?

Tags: xetex, hyperref, xindy

Unfortunately, as in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25623/how-to-use-xindy-with-xetex-luatex/251309#251309), I can't get it to “just work”; is there some additional code needed to make it work with hyperref?

I used this on a XeLaTeX'd document (with hyperref)

```
xindy -M texindy -C utf8 filename.idx
```

but I'm getting the errors:

```
line nnnn: multiple @'s
```

(hundreds of these); and

```
WARNING: unknown cross-reference-class `hyperindexformat'! (ignored)
WARNING: Would replace complete index key by empty string, ignoring
 #<ordrule-regexp: '\\[a-zA-Z@]+ *' => '' :again NIL :only-at-start NIL>
ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string
```

There's no indication of where in the index file that last error was thrown, and there doesn't seem to be any facility for reporting or tracing errors by line number of the input file.

Comment: An example of a document showing the issue? My crystal ball is under maintenance. `;-)`

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80300/how-can-i-convince-hyperref-and-xindy-to-play-together-nicely ?