# What is the recommended indexing package?

Tags: memoir, indexing

There's a dizzying array of [indexing packages](https://www.ctan.org/topic/index) available on CTAN.

For my current project, I'm using LuaLaTeX, but most of the time I just use straight LaTeX (and on occasion XeTeX).

My needs for this project are pretty pedestrian: the book I'm typesetting is in English, and I don't need any sort of custom collation. However, it's not really clear to me what the best choice is.

EDIT:

I noticed that some of the packages make reference to the `memoir` class, which I am currently using.

Comment: of the packages i've used, the one i've come to favor is `imakeidx`.  because of the way that input is handled, a decision to have one or more than one index can be held off until quite a late point in writing; mark all the items that you want to index with a simple `\index{...}` and if a second index is wanted, it can be added simply by inserting an optional argument, `\index[xxx]{...}` to just the appropriate items rather than having to change anything more extensively.  but i have never used it with `memoir`, and don't know about that compatibility.

Comment: Why don't you start with no package and figure out which one fills any gaps you find frustrating if that happens?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Loading no package has that advantage, too. You can always add `imakeidx` later. I had issues with `imakeidx` although I can't now remember the details, so tend to avoid it. So I tend to load `makeidx` and only make things fancier if I need to.

Comment: I *want* `xindy` to be the general-purpose solution, but the fact is that it can be complicated to use (because it can do complicated things). Worse still is [its incompatibility with hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81728/8528). So, on the one occasion I had to generate multiple indices, I used `makeindex` with the `imakeidx` package (which has never given me trouble), and this project also used the `memoir` class. The only downside was that I had to manually sort one of the indices, which was tedious (but I needed to sort numbers without leading zeroes: `1.9.3` before `1.20.2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no 'best'. Really, the best choice is the one which enables you to work most efficiently and effectively. Which this is depends on your specific needs - not just languages, but encodings, format etc.

You do not ***need*** to load any package at all to create a basic index. The functionality is part of core LaTeX.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Here is some word\index{word}.
\input{\jobname.ind}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: simple index]

when compiled with `<pdf/xe/lua>latex` -> `makeindex <filename>` -> `<pdf/xe/lua>latex`.

I used pdfLaTeX but the engine is irrelevant: only the format matters here.

I would, however, recommend loading `makeidx` so that you can say

```
\printindex
```

rather than needing to input the index manually. *If* `imakeidx` doesn't cause trouble, it is very convenient. However, I tend to avoid it because it sometimes causes me trouble.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506372/index-not-generated-in-an-arabic-document?noredirect=1#comment1279297_506372