# "See:" index entries being ignored when using hyperref with xindy

Tags: hyperref, xindy

Here is an MWE (compile this with `lualatex --shell-escape MWE.tex`, you only need to compile once to get the problematic output):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\index{Lorem ipsum}
\index{Ipsum!Lorem|see{Lorem ipsum}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Here is the rendered index I get on this document<sup>1</sup>:

> [image: picture of rendered index]

As you can see, the entry `\index{Ipsum!Lorem|see{Lorem ipsum}}` is missing. Taking a look at the output of `lualatex` (this does not appear in the transcript file)<sup>2</sup>:

```
Reading raw-index "C:\\Users\\ruben\\Dropbox\\Dokumente\\LaTeX\\hyperref-xindy-mwe\\BjciH3A8V8"...
WARNING: unknown cross-reference-class `hyperindexformat'! (ignored)
Finished reading raw-index.
```

Taking a look at the `MWE.idx` file, we can see this instance of `hyperindexformat`:

```
\indexentry{Lorem ipsum|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{Ipsum!Lorem|hyperindexformat{\see{Lorem ipsum}}}{1}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The full rendered PDF file can be found and downloaded on [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/RAnders00/bc47cb900fe63da0920fbd978c280f0b).</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Full command output and transcript files can be found in [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/RAnders00/9cd4d06fa4932bd4105475fd8f7815f9).</sup>

Comment: I did not get the output you are showing here using you [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). I do get `Lorem, see Lorem ipsum` as part of the output. Have you remembered to typeset it twice?

Comment: @RunarTrollet: I did typeset it twice (and even thrice), but you should be able to see it the first time (given you use the `--shell-escape` option). What TeX distribution are you using? I am using TexLive 2016 on Windows x64.

Comment: @RunarTrollet: Update: I just tried my MWE in a fresh Windows VM with MikTex (opposed to TexLive) and Strawberry Perl and I got the same issue.

Comment: @RunarTrollet: Another update: Just tried this with TexLive on Ubuntu 16.04.1 (again fresh VM). Same issue. What system are you using? Are you sure you used the exact MWE as provided with the supplied compilation command?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you. I don't have any experience with indices, I am running TexLive 2016 on macOS Sierra. I typeset it with `makeindex` though.

Comment: @RunarTrollet Well, the catch is that this question is xindy-related, that's why I asked you to include the `--shell-escape`

Comment: Comming here with the same issue is a bit frustrating, as the issue seems to [go back quite a bit](http://xindy-discuss.narkive.com/YIJLbw6C/new-hyperref-specifications-leads-to-unknown-cross-reference-class-hyperindexformat), yet no progress

Comment: Most of this questions seems to be answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80300/19326)